# Finding sum of the series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$(n-1) + (n-1)(n-2) + (n-1)(n-2)(n-3) +
\ldots+ (n-1)(n-2)...(n-k)+\dots$

How do I find the sum of the above series ? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You find it for a few small values of $n$, then look it up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: you can rewrite this sum as $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k}k!$

Comment: oh well, if you know the answer all you have to do is to use induction...

Comment: If $a_n$ is your sum, then show $a_{n+1}=n(1+a_n)$.

Comment: I don't think the given answer works - try small values of $n$. Are you sure it's for the correct problem?

Comment: For even $n$, the sum is odd, because all its terms are even except $n-1$; so it can't be $n^2\cdot 2^n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Factoring out $(n-1)!$, you get: $$(n-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{1}{k!}=(n-1)!e-1-f(n),$$ where $\frac{1}{n}<f(n)<\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}+\cdots =\frac{1}{n-1}\leq 1,$ when $n>1$. Since the left side is an integer, you get the value is  $$\lfloor(n-1)!e\rfloor -1.$$

This increases too fast to be $n^22^n$.